# Python pandas - processing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, memory

I appreciate any help as Im a bit desperate!

Im trying to filter out a 110k row and 46 column dataframe and apply some summarization. Its a whole pipeline that extracts the data from postgres, stores it into a DF and goes through a series of filters, everthing on memory.

My first execution runs smoothly, everything goes as expected, but as soon as I execute  the script again (short period of time), Im finding duplicates or missing ids when filtering out.

Lets put it this way:

[image]

Here, sometimes the last two **transaction_id** (from top to bottom) get duplicated as in the picture, and sometimes I get only the first two transaction_id (36739792, 36740873).
The source is fine no questions about it.

After some time (5 min at least) I execute the script and I get the expected results, it just works fine, which in this case would be only the first four transaction_id. The issue comes when re-executing in a short period.

When debugging line by line actually, I get everything right, so this makes me think the logic is not the issue.

**Could this be a memory issue? maybe somehow the script just keeps holding data even after execution?**

Im using python 3.9, pandas and vscode.

Again, Appreciate any help. Regards.

Comment: If you really want people to help you, you have to give more information. At least show some code. Create a mini data frame - and show the code which you use to manipulate the data. I am pretty sure it is not a memory issue. But the code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Agreed - see this post on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on stack overflow. There is no way for us to help you answer this question without a good idea of what your workflow is. Is it possible for memory limits to cause problems in a workflow? sure! but this doesn't help you. Ideally, ask a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the best answers.